# Find closest value with condition

Tags: r, matrix, lapply

I have a function that finds me the nearest values for each row in a matrix. It then reports a list with an index of the nearest rows. However, I want it to exclude values if they are +1 in the first AND +1 in the second column away from a particular set of values (-1 in the first and -1 in the second column should also be removed). Moreover, +1 in first column and -1 in second column with respect to the values of interest should also be avoided.

As an example, if I want things closes to **c(2, 1),** it should accept c(3,1) or (2,2) or (1,1), but NOT c(3,2) and not c(1,0).

Basically, for an output to be reported either column 1 or column 2 should be a value of 1 away from a row of interest, but not both.

input looks like this

```
x
    v1 v2
[1,] 3 1
[2,] 2 1
[3,] 3 2
[4,] 1 2
[5,] 8 5

myfunc(x)
```

The output looks like this. Notice that the closest thing to row 2 ($V2 in output) is row 1,3,4. The answer should only be 1 though.

```
$V1
[1] 2 3

$V2
[1] 1 3 4

$V3
[1] 1 2

$V4
[1] 2

$V5
integer(0)
```

Here is myfunc

```
myfunc = function(t){
    d1 <- dist(t[,1]) 
    d2 <- dist(t[,2]) 
    dF <- as.matrix(d1) <= 1 & as.matrix(d2) <= 1
    diag(dF) <- NA
    colnames(dF) <- NULL
    dF2 <- lapply(as.data.frame(dF), which)
    return(dF2)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the rows that you want to find should differ from your reference element by +1 or -1 in one column and be identical in the other column. That means that the sum over the absolute values of the differences is exactly one. For your example `c(2, 1)`, this works as follows:

- `c(3, 1)`: difference is `c(1, 0)`, thus `sum(abs(c(1, 0))) = 1 + 0 = 1`
- `c(1, 1)`: difference is `c(-1, 0)`, thus `sum(abs(c(-1, 0))) = 1 + 0 = 1`
- etc.

The following function checks exactly this:

```
myfunc <- function(x) {
  do_row <- function(r) {
    r_mat <- matrix(rep(r, length = length(x)), ncol = ncol(x), byrow = TRUE)
    abs_dist <- abs(r_mat - x)
    return(which(rowSums(abs_dist) == 1))
  }
  return(apply(x, 1, do_row))
}
```

`do_row()` does the job for a single row, and then `apply()` is used to do this with each row. For your example, I get:

```
myfunc(x)
## [[1]]
## [1] 2 3
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] 1
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] 1
## 
## [[4]]
## integer(0)
## 
## [[5]]
## integer(0)
```

Using `sweep()`, one can write a shorter function:

```
myfunc2 <- function(x) {
  apply(x, 1, function(r) which(rowSums(abs(sweep(x, 2, r))) == 1))
}
```

But this seems harder to understand and it turns out that it is slower by about a factor two for your matrix `x`. (I have also tried it with a large matrix, and there, the efficiency seems about the same.)